# Database-Generated Human-Friendly Codes

Tags: sql-server, random

I'd like to create some human-friendly codes to identify my objects.

I'm thinking about using the following rules:

- 6-digit random number
- the first character is not zero
- each code has an [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) value of 2 or greater* from every other such code
- maybe a checksum too

I'd like my MS SQL database to enforce that the codes I use are not only each unique, but also conform to the above criteria too.

How would I write a database check constraint to enforce rules such as these?

How could I make the database use such numbers as default values for inserted rows?

**so a single keystroke typo won't retreive a different-than-intended record*

Answer (score 1):

Use a stored procedure to check whatever constraints you would like for inserted data.

A stored procedure can also be used to generate these things if needed.

Although letting the database do all this for you seems like a nice thing, doing it all in code can be easier to maintain in the long run(unless you have dedicated DBAs who love maintaining this kind of stuff).

I think your idea and algorithm is smart.  If you're going to go that far with the requirements, I would say a checksum is a great thing to have.  The checksum alone can catch typo errors, regardless of edit distance.

Comment: You're right.  With a simple single-digit MOD 10 checksum added to a  simple unique number, I'd end up with edit distances of 2 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored proc that calculates your numeric value; use that stored proc as the `DEFAULT()` value for the column definition in your table definition.  Note: I haven't tried this, so I don't know if it's completely possible.

Answer (score 1):

How many id's do you need?

You could declare the column as an identity, and set the start value to 100000, and the increment to 12.  That would produce a six digit number, with edit distance of 2.

Also, as a bonus, this is pretty fast. But you may run out of numbers as this isn't all that dense.

```
CREATE TABLE [Items]
(
    [id] int IDENTITY(100000,12) NOT NULL primary key,
    [Data] varchar(50) NULL
)
```

Comment: I'll have to think about that.  I may need another digit.

Comment: I'd also rather that the numbers are in a random order so they don't imply unintended information such as the total number of records.

Answer (score 1):

Your enemy as far as UI goes is code length. I suggest you add alphabetic characters (omitting zero, oh, one, and eye). It will cut then length substantially, and make collisions less likely, especially for transpositions.

Answer (score 0):

Write a one-time-use program to populate a table of all (or many) possible valid codes in a scrambled order with an integer primary key.

Code table:

```
Id   HumanFriendlyCode

1    100124
2    991302
3    201463
4    157104
...  ...
```

Then just relate the objects table to the rows in that codes table with an auto-incrementing integer foreign key and a unique constraint.

Thing table:

```
Id                                    CodeId  ...

e9d29b14-0ea6-4cfd-a49f-44bcaa7212eb  1       ...
91906bb7-14ed-4acc-bf23-c4bd1631797f  2       ...
41ace075-f9f8-46b7-b114-cb17765c4e76  3       ...
2fba1a58-7a91-4da6-a4a2-7cacef8603db  4       ...
```

Anyone ever done something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This check constraint will enforce a checksum in a database column:

```
ALTER TABLE tblCode
ADD CHECK (
    CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(Code AS VARCHAR), 6, 1) AS INTEGER) =
    (
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(Code AS VARCHAR), 1, 1) AS INTEGER) +
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(Code AS VARCHAR), 2, 1) AS INTEGER) +
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(Code AS VARCHAR), 3, 1) AS INTEGER) +
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(Code AS VARCHAR), 4, 1) AS INTEGER) +
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(Code AS VARCHAR), 5, 1) AS INTEGER)
    ) % 10
)
```

The sixth digit must be modulo 10 of the sum of the first five digits.